# Create worker from data URI

Tags: javascript, worker

I have a very simple need, I need to spawn a webworker with a small data uri script:

```
new Worker('data:,console.log("HI")');
```

In Firefox this is giving me instead an error. Error is:

```
 SecurityError: Failed to load worker script at "data:,console.log("HI")"
```

Is there anyway to get worker to work with data URI?

Comment: The argument for `Worker()` is a script URL, not code.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker

Comment: Your code snippet works fine for me (in the console, anyway) in Firefox 49 (but evidently not in Chrome). What version are you using?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard thanks for testing! What  I ended up dong was using `Blob.createObjectURL` and then launch the worker with that.

Comment: Try https://github.com/Wildhoney/Freelancer

Comment: Very interesting thank you @Wildhoney if you can post that as solution I would love to accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely try [`Freelancer`](https://github.com/Wildhoney/Freelancer) which:

- Takes a `function` that it transforms to a string using `Function.prototype.toString`
- Creates an IIFE from the passed function and passes in any additional arguments
- Transforms the function into a `Blob` with `application/javascript` as the type
- Instantiates the new worker with the data URI created with `URL.createObjectURL`.

Answer (score 0):

Freelancer is equivalent to these 5 lines of code (if you don't care about error messages when your browser doesn't support Web Workers).

```js
class Worker extends globalThis.Worker {
    constructor(fn, ...params) {
        return super(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`(${fn.toString()})(${params.map(JSON.stringify)})`], {type: 'application/javascript'})))
    }
}
```